# Order of element 2 in group $\Bbb{Z^*_{47}}$ under multiplication

Tags: group-theory

What is the order of element 2 in group ($\Bbb{Z^*_{47}}$,x) ?

Got no clue from where to start any help would be great

Comment: It's a factor of $46$. Is $2$ a quadratic residue modulo $47$?

Comment: Saying you don't know where to start does not make much sense. In the last resort you could just work it out, and use a calculator if that helps.

Comment: Hint: $2\equiv 49 \bmod 47$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us use that computer help. This and similar problems can be best covered by using computer algebra systems, like [sage](http://www.mathsage.org). So here is the sage dialog, then there will come come comments:

```
sage: 47.is_prime()
True
sage: F = GF(47)
sage: G = F.unit_group()
sage: G.order()
46
sage: G.is_cyclic()
True
sage: F(2).multiplicative_order()
23
```

Comments: First of all, we note that $47$ is a prime number. Then $\Bbb Z/47$ (integers taken modulo $47$) is a field, "the" field $F=\Bbb F_{47}$ with $47$ elements. There is a known structure theorem, its unit group $F^\times$ (i.e. $F$ "without zero", with the multiplication inherited from $F$) is a cyclic group. This group has $47-1=46$ elements. Due to a theorem of Lagrange, the order of each element in this (or another finite) group divides the order of the group.

So the element $2$ (modulo $47$) has a multiplicative order among the divisors of $46$. These divisors are $1,2,23,46$. One has to exclude $1,2,46$. The $1$, $2$ are immediately excluded, $2^1$ and $2^4$ are not $1$ modulo $47$. The argument in the comments also exclude the $46$. In the following way. (If one did not see this before, then it is didactically better to give the answer.)

```
sage: sqrt(F(2))
7
```

There is a "square root" of $2$ in the field, $7^2 =49=47+2=0+2=2$ in $F$. This $7$ also has a multiplicative order, which divides $46$. It is $23$ or $46$. (It is $23$, but we do not need this.) In both cases, the order of $2=7^2$ is $23$.

Comment: legend thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since $47$ is prime, $\Bbb{Z}^*_{47}$ has order $47-1=46=2 \cdot 23$.

Therefore, the only possible orders for elements in $\Bbb{Z}^*_{47}$ are $1,2,23,46$.

The order of $2$ is clearly not $1$ or $2$. As mentioned in the comments, $2 \equiv 49 = 7^2 \bmod 47$ and so $2^{23} \equiv 7^{46} \equiv 1$ by Fermat. Therefore, the order of $2$ cannot be $46$ and so must be $23$.